# Can a number be a subset of another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

For example, if I had a set `A = {2,4,6}` is `2 ⊂ A` true?

Comment: Definitely no. It is $2\in A$ or $\{2\}\subset A.$ That is, $2$ is an element of $A$ but $2$ is not a subset of $A.$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Does this also mean that Ø ⊂ A would be false?

Comment: I don't know that it's acceptable to say the number by itself is a subset, but the singleton set containing only that element is indeed a subset, i.e. $\{2\}\subset A$.

Comment: @user3517647 $\emptyset \subset A$ for any $A.$ Note that any element of $\emptyset$ is an element of $A.$

Comment: To be clear @mfl, I am asking if Ø ⊂ A is true, not {Ø} ⊂ A. Do these mean the same thing?

Comment: @user3517647 $\emptyset \subset A$ is always true, for any $A.$ However, $\{\emptyset\}\not\subset \mathbb{N},$ since $\emptyset$ is not a natural number.

Comment: @mfl Great, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true. $2 \in \{2,4,6\}$ and $\{2\}\subset \{2,4,6\}$.

However the way natural numbers may be defined is $0=\{\}$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{1,0\}$, ... This is a very common definition, and it shows that $1\in 2$ as counter intuitive as that sounds. This is how natural numbers are defined in set theory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

This last part is the answer to your title question "can a number be a subset of another set". This is a resounding YES! But the question in your body has an answer of no.

Comment: Just a small detail. This is a definiton of the natural numbers. There are others.

Answer (score 0):

A subset is also a set, so the answer is no (although there are definitions of the number two as a set but that doesn't seem to be the case here)